# Tengo una tabla, los checkbox se genera automáticamente ¿como les asigno una función?

Tags: c#, asp

Holaaa amigos buen día..!! disculpen mi ignorancia apenas me estoy adentrando a este lenguaje..

Tengo n registos en mi tabla, por cada fila se va agregando un checkbox automaticamente, ¿como puedo saber que checkbox esta seleccionado?.. para poder modificar o eliminar el registro de acuerdo al checkbox seleccionado

en la parte del foreach se va agregando el checkbox

```
private void TablaAdminContCarga(DataTable tablaEntrada)
{
    int i = 1;
    //DataTable dt = this.GetData();
    DataTable dt = tablaEntrada;

    //Construyendo una cadena HTML.
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    //Table start.
    html.Append("<table class='table table-striped table-bordered text-center'>" +
        "<thead>" +
        "<tr class='tituloTabla'>");

    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("#");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("No. Folio Contrato");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("ID Socio Comercial");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("Tipo Cotrato");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("No. de BRM");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("<th scope='col' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>");
    html.Append("No. de Orden de Compra");
    html.Append("</th>");

    html.Append("</tr>" +
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody> ");

    //Construyendo las filas de datos.
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        html.Append("<th scope='row' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>" + i + "</th>");
        html.Append("<td><input type= 'checkbox' id = chbGrid'" + i + "' /></td>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</td>");
        }

        html.Append("</tr>");
        i++;
    }
    //Table end.
    html.Append("</tbody>" +
        "</table>");
    //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
    tbAdminCont.Text = html.ToString();
}
```

Me carga los registros y los checkbox sin problema, pero no logro identificar el checkbox seleccionado... :c

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar gracias por adelantado...
Saludos.!!

Comment: porque generas html de esa forma armando un string ? eso no esta bueno. Has puesto el tag de asp, pero eso que significa que es asp.net o asp.net mvc, porque hay mejores forma de definir html dinamico

Comment: Si quieres manejarlo así, tendrías que crear código en el cliente (javascript) para capturar el evento y eliminar esa fila (esto solamente si la eliminación es sólo en el front), si es una eliminación en una BD entonces tendrías que hacer post back con javascript enviando datos (como ids) para identificar la fila seleccionada en donde se encuentra el checkbox pero para éste último caso te recomendaría usar la tecnología que manejes que sería importante que la menciones ya que ASP puede ser ASP, ASP.NET o ASP.NET MVC (3,4,5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aún que no es una forma habitual de crear HTML, suponemos que lo necesitas. Pero la funcionalidad de recoger el valor donde lo quieres tratar? Por ejemplo en javascript puedes hacer simplemente con:

```
let valor = elementoHTML.options[elementoHTML.selectedIndex].value;
```